# Can you solve this Diophantine equation really fast: $31x + 30y + 29z = 366$

Tags: diophantine-equations, puzzle

Is there a "trick" to finding a solution $(x,y,z)$ of the Diophantine equation $$31x + 30y + 29z = 366$$ where $0 \leq z \leq y \leq x $?

Comment: Yes. Happy New Year!

Comment: @JoeyZou "Leap year" would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hint: How many months have $31$ days?  $30$ days?  $29$ days?

Comment: $(6,6,0)\,$, $(7, 4, 1)\,$, $(8, 2, 2)\,$, $(9, 0, 3)\,$ ...hmm ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$$31*6=186$$

Then see $60=31+29$ and you can sum $30$'s and $60$'s to get the condition.

$$366=31*7+30*4+29*1$$

Comment: Huh? $31\cdot 6 + 30\cdot 4 + 29\cdot 0 = 306$.

Comment: Sorry the mistake, correcting. I didn't add the $+1$ to 31 and 29.

Answer (score 1):

Solving $(N+1)x + Ny = M$ is the same as dividing $M$ by $N$: $366 = 30*12 + 6 = 31*6 + 30*6$. $z$ equals $0$.